# Windows: Is there any way to disable UI resizing?

Tags: windows, mouse, gui, window

I'm on Windows. As I always insist on the default appearances of GUI, I want to prevent accidental resizing (e.g. window resizing, column resizing). Any way to disable resizing (like they are locked)? Or less preferably by disabling mouse dragging function?

Thanks - I'm sort of OCD and have to restore the system every time such unwanted UI modifications are made, faithfully stuck on the defaults (of the quantitative settings such as for UI).

Comment: what kind of programs are we talking? I know that i can set programs to a Fixed window thats not resizable in programs that I write, but I don't know about forcing sizing on other programs.